# Missed email outside working hours

Tags: professionalism, email, meetings, clients

I've searched everywhere about this but can't find anything, so I might as well ask here.

My office is closed on Saturdays (which is quite a hard thing to find in my city) and Sundays of course. Regardless, I've synced all my emails to my phone and check them every now and then including during the weekend.

Now, I am sure that I was checking my email sometimes around lunch on Saturday, but that's it. Since it's a day off, so I spend the rest of the weekend with the family.

However, on Monday morning when I checked my email I just knew that one of my client (a sales person from a hotel) is inviting me for a Sunday Brunch. The sent date of the email was Saturday at 3 pm.

I don't mind replying a business email on a day off, but she sent the email so late in the day, for an event held in the next day. I would like to politely respond to her email though. What do you think I should write?

Thank you.

Comment: this is a very specific question which is probably why you're getting downvoted. However, surely you just respond as you would to anyone, 'sorry I missed your email, can we reschedule for x date'?

Answer (score 17):

"Thanks for the invitation to brunch, unfortunately I didn't see your email in time. Would love to catch up with you some other time!"

Anything more would seem to be wildly overthinking it.

Comment: think you're missing a word after catch...

Comment: @Jake thanks! and thanks to HLGEM for fixing it already! :-)